# Define TypeScript type based on generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's have SQL database table with column `data` of type JSON and this enum in TypeScript (4.0.5):

```js
enum EContentType {
  NOTHING,
  IMAGE,
  VIDEO
}
```

Depending on `ContentType` I am saving different JSON schema into `data` column into my database.

Example:

- For `IMAGE`, saving `{"path": "/foo/bar", "type": "jpeg"}`
- For `VIDEO`, saving `{"path": "/foo/bar", "length": 60}`

Is possible to create TypeScript type for this `data` object with generics what will be correctly typed based on `EContentType`?

Something like (pseudo):

```js
type TDataType<ContentType> = {
   [ContentType.IMAGE]: {path: string, type: string}
   [ContentType.VIDEO]: {path: string, length: number}
}
```

Usage:

```js
const concreteType: EContentType = EcontentType.IMAGE;

const typedDataField = dataField as TDataType<concreteType>;
```

Is this possible? Or it is not, because TypeScript is only statically typed...
Any different idea how to guarantee type safety (not allow someone to save `length` property for `IMAGE` content type)?

If there is no way to do it what about type what will work like this:

```js
const data1 = dbDataField as TDataType<EContentType.IMAGE> // {path: string, type: string}
const data2 = dbDataField as TDataType<EContentType.VIDEO> // {path: string, length: number}
```

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work as you're declaring `ContentType` as a type but using it as a value. A better approach would be to use an interface and `extends` your desired properties on generic for anything you would want predefined

```
interface TDataType <T>{
   [key: string]: T
}

let a: TDataType<{path: string, type: string}>;
a.IMAGE = {path: 'aaa', type: 'bbbb'};
console.log(a); // output:  "IMAGE": {"path": "aaa", "type": "bbbb"}
```

or use The `Record<Keys, type>` utility type to define https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype

```
interface Content{
  path: string, type: string
}

type ContentType = "IMAGE" | "VIDEO";

const concreteType: Record<ContentType , Content> = {
  IMAGE: { path: "", type: ""}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type TDataType = {
  [key in EContentType]: {path: string, type: string}
}

type TDataType2<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: { path: string; type: string };
};
```

You can use like this.

---

example)

```
enum EContentEnum {
  NOTHING,
  IMAGE,
  VIDEO,
}

type TDataType2<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: { path: string; type: string };
};

const contentData: Pick<TDataType2<typeof EContentEnum>, 'IMAGE'> = {
  IMAGE: {
    path: 'imagePath',
    type: 'imageType',
  },
};

contentData.IMAGE
```

This is my answer, but I am not sure if you want it.

Comment: This seem like it will not work... I need to have generic dynamic, not statically written into code. I added `Usage:` example into question.

Comment: Sorry, it is not helped... I think typescript not supported dynamic type. just supported static type.

Comment: I know, thats why I asked :/ And what about type based on static generic? Like so: `TDataType<EContentType.IMAGE>`

Comment: I don't recommended `TDataType<EContentType.IMAGE>`, becuase `TDataType2<EContentEnum>` is include type you want.

Comment: Ok, but how you define multiple objects in one type then? I dont see it in your example

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but here is a possible solution:

```js
enum EContentType {
    NOTHING,
    IMAGE,
    VIDEO,
}
type TBaseDataType = {
    path: string;
};
interface IImageType extends TBaseDataType{
    type: string;
}
interface IVideoType extends TBaseDataType {
    length: number;
}
type TDataType<T extends EContentType = EContentType.IMAGE> = T extends EContentType.IMAGE ? IImageType : IVideoType;

const image: TDataType<EContentType.IMAGE>;
```

This is just an example, but it allows you to use the same type and dynamically select the desired image or video type.